# Is it possible to have non reapating element in an xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xmldocument

I m working on a simple adventure game and right now I have an xml file to load the world and another for the player.

here is the simplified xml I'd like to create:

```
<root>
   <world>
        <location>
           //room 1
             <inventory>
                  talble, chair...
             </inventory>
        </location> 
        <location>
             //room 2
        </location>
   </world>
   <player>
       //some player stats i.e the location he is currently in.
       <inventory>
           the player bag containing objects
       </inventory>
   </player>
</root>
```

Will I be able to parse that file to get the player inventory or a location inventory? is it allowed to create that asymetrical xml or does it always have to be only repeating element?

Right now the game works but I am not sure it's good practice to separate those too files since I must always update theim at the same time. I'd rather merge those together.

Thanks a lot for the help.
Mike

Comment: "Will I be able to parse that file to get the player inventory or a location inventory?" Did you actually _try_ something out? BTW: Using a [DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx) , you can easily export and import your whole DataModel to XML using DataSet's built in [Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb27k0tf(v=vs.110).aspx)/[Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/360dye2a(v=vs.110).aspx) functionality.

Comment: I'm really starting xml and it took me a very long time to have everything working... so if I must restart everything and blow my working code I would prefer to know it is possible and good practice before.

Comment: You will probably want to add some kind of identifier to your rooms (and other elements), in case you ever need to be able to store references to specific elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XDocument` provides methods to access specific elements via a "path".

To get all elements of the player's inventory, you would need code similar to this:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> playerItems = x.Element("player").Element("inventory").Elements();
```

And to get the objects of the first location:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> locationObjects = x.Element("world").Elements("location").First().Element("inventory").Elements();
```

Note the difference between `Element()` and `Elements()`, the first returns only one element; the second returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>`.
This is important when you want to retrieve the objects of all locations.

After you have retrieved all elements, you would need to process them; you can access the value of an element by the `Value` property which is a `String`.